# EntityFramework Context is not saved

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, exception, dbcontext

I have some actions to my DbContext for save.

I have two Entities - Material and Colors. The entities have relationship many to many.

I try to do this:

```
var color = context
 .Colors
 .Include("Materials")
 .Where(g => g.Id == (colorId))
 .FirstOrDefault();
var mater = context
 .Materials
 .Include("Colors")
 .SingleOrDefault(c => c.Name == material.Name);
mater.Colors.Add(color);
context.SaveChanges();
```

When program try to run `context.SaveChanges()`, it throws an exception `DbUpdateException`

```
Unable to update the EntitySet 'MaterialColors' because it has a 
DefiningQuery and no <InsertFunction> element exists in 
the <ModificationFunctionMapping> element to support the current operation.
```

How to solve it?

Comment: database is Sql 2008 express. ModelFirst

Comment: It's an strange problem in the model. How does you MaterialColors table look like? Does it only have the two FK making a PK?

Comment: MaterialsColors table is created by model, where I set between Materials and Colors Many to many. This table haven't PK

Comment: So I guess the table only has the two FKs. Try removing the relation from the model and updating it from the DB. There is a problem in your model because it's trying to use an stored proc to insert values in that table. Are you using EF 4.0 or other version?

Comment: I forgot it: back up your model files before this test.

Comment: In this project I have EF 4.1.0.0. Thanks for the advice. I write there result of test.

Comment: I forgot othe thing: try also adding a PK to the table, including both FKs and updating the model from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every table mapped by EF must have PK. If it doesn't have PK it will be mapped as readonly view. You must go to your database and in `MaterialColors` mark both FKs as composite PK. Than update your model.